# Visual Studio Mac extensions mpack failure

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Visual Studio Mac Extensions mpack file installation failed with below error

Error:

The add-in  Mytemplate could not be updated because  some of its dependencies missing  or not  compatible

required:Mono.Develop.Core 8.2.5 , found : MonoDevelop.Core 8.1.2
required:Mono.Develop.Ide 8.2.5 , found : MonoDevelop.Ide8.1.2

Answer (score 0):

> required:Mono.Develop.Core 8.2.5 and required:Mono.Develop.Ide

Is there some mistakes here, should them be `MonoDevelop.Core 8.2.5 and MonoDevelop.Ide`?

> The add-in Mytemplate could not be updated because some of its
>   dependencies missing or not compatible

Please check [this document](https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/creating-a-simple-add-in/#creating-the-addin), I guess the reason why you get that issue is the extension you want to install is for `MonoDevelop 8.2.5` designed by the add-in maker while the version in your machine is `8.1.2`.

Check this [monodevelop add-in repository](http://addins.monodevelop.com/) and you can find the extensions there target different versions of MonoDevelop. So for your issue I think you can try to get the Mytemplate extension for 8.1.2, or you can choose to update your VS for MAC and the MonoDevelop in your machine to latest version.